# Smooth parent transition on child "translateX"

Tags: html, css

On GIF below, there's parent div, which contain "left-menu" and "app-content". Left menu is animating, using keyframes and translate property

```css
#LeftMenuContainer {
    &.menu_hidden {
        animation: slide-out 0.6s forwards;
    }

    &.menu_shown {
        animation: slide-in 0.6s forwards;
    }
}
```

```css
@keyframes slide-in {
    0% { transform: translateX(-100%); width: 0; }
    100% { transform: translateX(0); width: auto; }
}

@keyframes slide-out {
    0% { transform: translateX(0); width: auto; }
    100% { transform: translateX(-100%); width: 0; }
}
```

DOM tree looks like this

```html
<div id="contentContainer" class="flex">
      <app-left-menu></app-left-menu>
      <div>Be smooth!</div>
</div>
```

Is there any way, to "smooth" transition parent width, when "left-menu" is hiding? I try to add styles for parent, with

```css
transition-property: width;
transition-duration: 0.6s;
```

but it doesn't work.

https://im2.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-2-a1f74da85c.gif

Answer (score 0):

Assume It only flickers when comes to animate, so you can try to use [will-change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change), [css-will-change-property](https://dev.opera.com/articles/css-will-change-property/)

> The `will-change` CSS property hints to browsers how an element is expected to change. Browsers may set up optimizations before an element is actually changed

If you are using framework like `React` can try to use [framer-motion](https://www.framer.com/docs/)